# How to detect cell click in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to detect what specific cell was clicked in DataGrid?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for the [selectedindexchanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event

Comment: Not exactly. I need to detect it before selection changes.

Comment: This is for a webpage right? Then you will have to write your own javascript for that. Using jquery it won't be hard. See example here http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @user62658 he didn't see the tags, correct but please relax ppl

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to handle CellClik or CellContentClick events?

Comment: There aren't such events in DataGrid :-/

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I haven't found this answer as well, (To determine a cell click).
And suppose I wanted to use it to be able to check/uncheck a checkbox, upon first click.

Then I guess the designer of this library would not approve of doing, it the following way, (I can (de)select my checkbox this way, but it seems unwise/dangerous as your changing the selected item property of the grid.)

So what we need is someone telling us how we can detect a cell's click otherwise some of us
   may want to use the selectionchanged event, the bad thing about this is that you lose info on
   which row of the grid pass pressed.

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridInstance.SelectedItem != null)
    {
    //do what you need to do with the data. (for example start with:)
    Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellInfo datagridCellInfo = dataGridInstance.CurrentCell;

    //when you are done, set selectiTem to null, so even upon a next click on the same          
    //cell this method will be called again
    dataGridTeam.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```